# How to find the dimension of the intersection of hyperplanes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let P ⊂ R4 be the subspace with equation 2x + 3y − z + w = 0, let Q ⊂ R4 be the hyper-plane with equation x + y −z = 0, let R ⊂ R4 be the hyper-plane with equation x−y + w = 0, and let l = P∩Q∩R.

I know that l is a subspace because it is the intersection of 3 subspaces, and I am looking for it's dimension. I'm not sure how to find this, I put the equations in an augmented matrix and row reduced, but I have no idea what to do with this result. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four unknowns $(x,y,z,w)$ and three homogeneous equations, so we can write this using a $3\times 4$ matrix $M$ and you want to find the dimension of the kernel of $M$ (a.k.a. the nullity). By [the rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) you can find it as $\dim(\mathbb R^4)-\textrm{rank}(M)$.

Explicitly,
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&-1&1\\1&1&-1&0\\1&-1&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has rank $3$, since the rightmost three columns are linearly independent. Thus, the dimension of the subspace is $1$, it is a line.

If you have trouble seeing why the rightmost three columns are linearly independent, you can do it by showing that the third-from-right column can not be written as a linear combination of the two rightmost columns - since if you could, then there would be only one way to match up the lower two entries (taking $-1$ times each of the rightmost two columns) but then the top entry wouldn't match.